# How to change width and height of CKEditorField of flask-ckeditor?

Tags: python, flask, ckeditor

I tried this:

```
{% block tail %}
   {{ super() }}
   {{ ckeditor.load() }}
   {{ ckeditor.config(width=200) }}
{% endblock %}
```

I tried with different height and width values but it's not modifying.

Answer (score 2):

When using Flask-Admin, you have to specify field name you overwritten with `form_overrides = dict(text=CKEditorField)`
([docs](https://flask-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#custom-configuration-string)). This also applies for wtf-forms - you have to specify `name` by field name, you made in form class . Well when you want to specify just width, it could be better way to adjust it with some css (may look better). Anyways code should look like this:

```
{% block tail %}
   {{ super() }}
   {{ ckeditor.load() }}
   {{ ckeditor.config(name='text',width=300) }}
{% endblock tail %}
```

Also you can use [custom_config](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html), to set it up.

```
{{ ckeditor.config(name='text',custom_config="width: '80%'") }}
```

If you wouldn't use flask-admin and you created ckeditor through `ckeditor.create()` the value of name is set in default to `name="ckeditor"` so you don't have to specify `name` in `.config()` ([docs](https://flask-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#register-configuration)):

```
{{ ckeditor.load() }}
{{ ckeditor.create() }}
{{ ckeditor.config(width=200) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use config variable `CKEDITOR_HEIGHT` and `CKEDITOR_WDITH`, for example:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_ckeditor import CKEditor

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CKEDITOR_HEIGHT'] = 1000  # px
app.config['CKEDITOR_WDITH'] = 400  # px

ckeditor = CKEditor(app)
```

See all available configuration in [docs](https://flask-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#available-configuration).

Answer (score 0):

You can append a script after loading CKEditor:

```
{% block tail %}
    {{ super() }}
    {{ ckeditor.load() }}
    {{ ckeditor.config(name='body') }}
  <script>
    CKEDITOR.addCss(".cke_editable{cursor:text; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;}");
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```